# "Incorrect" Password Loading Encrypted OpenSSH Key

Tags: vb.net, ssh-keys, ecdsa, chilkat, chilkat-sshkey

I am trying to set up an application to use a `Chilkat.SshKey` to read my ECDSA 521-bit OpenSSH key for authentication to a new SSH server. I've read [documentation](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refDoc/csSshKeyRef.html) and [examples](https://www.example-code.com/csharp/sshkey_loadFromFile.asp) from the developers but I still get an error every time I try to load the key:

```
ChilkatLog:
  FromOpenSshPrivateKey(32ms):
    DllDate: May 25 2017
    ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.68
    UnlockPrefix: <mycode>
    Architecture: Little Endian; 32-bit
    Language: .NET 4.5
    VerboseLogging: 1
    fromOpenSshPrivateKey(32ms):
      loadPem2(32ms):
        loadPem(16ms):
          itemType: OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY
          addPemItem(16ms):
            itemType: OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY
            loadAnyDerPw(16ms):
              DecodeToAsn:
                premature end of BER encoding (F2)
                length: 115
                numBytesLeft: 108
              --DecodeToAsn
              loadAnyAsn:
                Invalid ASN.1 for public/private key
              --loadAnyAsn
              der_to_xml:
                ASN data length exceeds remaining number of bytes available.
                tag: 19
                idClass: 1
                bConstructed: 1
                headerLen: 2
                dataLen: 115
                inlen: 108
                Abort ASN.1 processing...
                recursiveDepth: 2
                Abort ASN.1 processing...
                recursiveDepth: 1
              --der_to_xml
              der_xml: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<application tag="15" constructed="1">
    <application tag="5" constructed="1" />
</application>

            --loadAnyDerPw
          --addPemItem
          No more -----BEGIN's found.
        --loadPem
      --loadPem2
      Check the password, it may be incorrect.
    --fromOpenSshPrivateKey
    Failed.
  --FromOpenSshPrivateKey
--ChilkatLog
```

I've verified the password is correct by using `ssh-keygen -y -f <path_to_private_key>`. My code looks like this:

```vb
Dim MyKey As New SshKey With {.Password = "<private_key_password>", .VerboseLogging = True}
Dim SSHKeyString As String = MyKey.LoadText("<path_to_private_key>")

If Not MyKey.FromOpenSshPrivateKey(SSHKeyString) Then
    Throw New Exception("Failed to load the private key." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & MyKey.LastErrorText)
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Private key loaded successfully")
End If
```

Initially, I had tried reading the file from a server share but, when I tried the `ssh-keygen` command, it was giving me an error:

```
Bad permissions. Try removing permissions for user: MYDOMAIN\\Domain Admins (sid) on file //SERVER/SSH/my-key-ecdsa.
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions for '\\\\SERVER\\SSH\\my-key-ecdsa' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "\\\\SERVER\\SSH\\my-key-ecdsa": bad permissions
```

I copied the file to a local drive and removed permissions for all but myself (my domain user) and was able to get the `ssh-keygen` command to correctly return the key information:

```
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 <KEY CONTENTS HERE> ssh@mydomain.com
```

Just to be sure, I also tested with a garbage password and it returned:

```
Load key "<path_to_private_key>": incorrect passphrase supplied to decrypt private key
```

What is it that I'm missing here?

---

Just to try to provide as much information as possible, here's an obfuscated/redacted version of the private key in question:

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
[line 1]
[line 2]
[line 3]
[...]
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

None of the example keys on the [documentation page](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refDoc/csSshKeyRef.html#method0) show this specific structure but, from the way the `.LastErrorText` reads, that doesn't appear to be the issue I'm facing.

---

Looking at [Loading encrypted key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57794325/2569697), I started wondering if the issue may be that there's a punctuation character in the password I used to encrypt the key. Unfortunately, that doesn't appear to be the cause of the error.

I created a new key with the same parameters:

```
ssh-keygen -f "C:\temp_folder\test-key-ecdsa" -t ecdsa -b 521 -C ssh@mydomain.com
```

I encrypted it with a simple password of `testpass`, but I'm still getting effectively the same `.LastErrorText` result with `Check the password, it may be incorrect.`

Next, I created a key with no password:

```
ssh-keygen -f "C:\temp_folder\nopass-key-ecdsa" -t ecdsa -b 521 -C ssh@mydomain.com
```

This time, at least, I got a different error:

```
ChilkatLog:
  FromOpenSshPrivateKey(47ms):
    DllDate: May 25 2017
    ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.68
    UnlockPrefix: <mycode>
    Architecture: Little Endian; 32-bit
    Language: .NET 4.5
    VerboseLogging: 1
    fromOpenSshPrivateKey(47ms):
      loadPem2(31ms):
        loadPem(31ms):
          itemType: OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY
          addPemItem(31ms):
            itemType: OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY
            loadAnyDerPw(16ms):
              DecodeToAsn:
                premature end of BER encoding (F2)
                length: 115
                numBytesLeft: 108
              --DecodeToAsn
              loadAnyAsn:
                Invalid ASN.1 for public/private key
              --loadAnyAsn
              der_to_xml:
                ASN data length exceeds remaining number of bytes available.
                tag: 19
                idClass: 1
                bConstructed: 1
                headerLen: 2
                dataLen: 115
                inlen: 108
                Abort ASN.1 processing...
                recursiveDepth: 2
                Abort ASN.1 processing...
                recursiveDepth: 1
              --der_to_xml
              der_xml: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<application tag="15" constructed="1">
    <application tag="5" constructed="1" />
</application>

            --loadAnyDerPw
          --addPemItem
          No more -----BEGIN's found.
        --loadPem
      --loadPem2
      Did you forget to set the Password property on this SshKey object prior to loading this private key?
    --fromOpenSshPrivateKey
    Failed.
  --FromOpenSshPrivateKey
--ChilkatLog
```

I tried both by removing the `.Password` property of the `Chilkat.SshKey` object constructor, as well as by explicitly setting it to `String.Empty` and `Nothing`, but get the same results each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this issue was caused by an outdated version of the library and has since been resolved. As the `.LastErrorText` showed, I was using v9.5.0.68 from May 25, 2017. I've been using this library in my application for quite a while, but I've never had a need to use SSH keys for authentication before.

On a lark, I created a new console application (.NET 6.0) and installed the latest `ChilkatDnCore` library (v9.50.95) from NuGet. I then tested all three of the keys with the following code:

```vb
Sub Main(args As String())
    Dim SSHComm As New Chilkat.SFtp
    Dim LibraryUnlocked As Boolean = CheckSSHComponent(SSHComm)
    Dim SSHKeyString As String
    Dim NoPassKey As New SshKey With {.VerboseLogging = True}

    SSHKeyString = NoPassKey.LoadText("C:\temp_folder\nopass-key-ecdsa")

    If Not NoPassKey.FromOpenSshPrivateKey(SSHKeyString) Then
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to load the private key: nopass-key-ecdsa")
        Console.WriteLine(NoPassKey.LastErrorText)
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Private key loaded successfully: nopass-key-ecdsa")
        Console.WriteLine(NoPassKey.KeyType)
    End If

    Dim TestKey As New SshKey With {.VerboseLogging = True, .Password = "testpass"}

    SSHKeyString = TestKey.LoadText("C:\temp_folder\test-key-ecdsa")

    If Not TestKey.FromOpenSshPrivateKey(SSHKeyString) Then
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to load the private key: test-key-ecdsa")
        Console.WriteLine(TestKey.LastErrorText)
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Private key loaded successfully: test-key-ecdsa")
        Console.WriteLine(TestKey.KeyType)
    End If

    Dim LiveKey As New SshKey With {.VerboseLogging = True, .Password = <live_key_password>}

    SSHKeyString = LiveKey.LoadText("C:\temp_folder\live-key-ecdsa")

    If Not LiveKey.FromOpenSshPrivateKey(SSHKeyString) Then
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to load the private key: live-key-ecdsa")
        Console.WriteLine(LiveKey.LastErrorText)
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Private key loaded successfully: live-key-ecdsa")
        Console.WriteLine(LiveKey.KeyType)
    End If
End Sub
```

The results were all successful:

```
Private key loaded successfully: nopass-key-ecdsa
ecdsa
Private key loaded successfully: test-key-ecdsa
ecdsa
Private key loaded successfully: live-key-ecdsa
ecdsa
```

So, I went back to my original application and removed the old, direct file reference to the Chilkat library I had and downloaded the latest version from NuGet with the Package Manager. Testing there was successful as well.

Finally, just to try to implement my original intent, I changed the path of the private key file back to the network share and tested one last time. Once again, everything was successful.

I admit that I've been avoiding upgrading the library for a while for fear of having to recode stuff, but I'm not seeing any other errors, so I guess that's all I needed.